# S3 Bucket similar solution in Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-s3, openshift, devops, cicd

I am new in DevOps amd I am deploying an application on Openshift where users can upload PDf / jpg ...

However, I am not sure if provisioning persists volume is enough, and how it's possible to display all these files later ( graphical interface ) . I need some solution similar to S3 bucket in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

MinIO provides a consistent, performant and scalable object store because it is Kubernetes-native by design and S3 compatible from inception.

https://min.io/product/private-cloud-red-hat-openshift

We have installed & tested minio in openshift 3.11 successfully.

Comment: Care to explain how we can install ?